# Accidentally ran chmod 775 -R / (not ./) on linux server (RedHat)

Tags: linux, redhat, shell

I accidentally ran `sudo chmod 775 -R /` instead of `sudo chmod 775 -R ./` on my server and screwed up the permissions for everything. Now the server is broken.

Anyone know how I can quickly fix this???

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/233764/revert-chmod-777-r

Comment: What distro are you using? There are a lot of similar questions: [How to repair/restore ubuntu 10.04 after 'sudo chmod / 777'](http://serverfault.com/q/221447/51929), [chmod -R 777 / on ubuntu - numerous problems](http://serverfault.com/q/141806/51929), ...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no quickly for this fix.  Look at the link provided by ooshro to find ways to reset permissions for packages.  As for the data on the system, that will probably have to be changed by hand.

Comment: its redhat. aargh

Comment: kernel 2.6.18-164.2.1.e15

Answer (score 12):

If this is a RPM based distribution, you can use the following command to reset permissions to the RPM defaults:

rpm --setperms $(rpm -qa)

It'll at least get you started on the path.

Answer (score 2):

You have backups, right? Hopefully ones that include both files and filesystem metadata? If this happened in my environment, I'd pull last night's backup down to fresh disks and get booted on that. Hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a lot of help if you didn't know about it or use it before, but you can backup permissions in a restorable way.  See [Backing up permissions on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/194285/backing-up-permissions-on-linux)